Slowness/Transfer rate going up and down on external 5TB Seagate hard drive via Samba?
My setup is the following:

I have an old laptop with 4GB RAM connected to LAN
The laptop runs Ubuntu 22.04 Server and functions as my home/media server
The laptop has a 5TB Seagate Expansion drive attached
The server provides access to the drive via Samba

The problem is that whenever I try to move things from my Windows PC onto the external drive via Samba, it accelerates up to 30 MB/s transfer speed, then dips to 0 bytes/s. This then repeats every minute or so.
I've not been able to find any solution to this behavior online. There are many questions about Linux transfers slowing down gradually over time, but never the kind of up-and-down motion I am experiencing.
htop shows that my RAM is always at about 250MB free remaining. The swapfile isn't being used at all. The CPUs only kick in when the transfer rate goes up, they're completely still when it's waiting at 0 bytes/s.
I tried checking the health of the external storage via SMART, but monitor tools are reporting unsupported field in scsi command.

I used lsusb to find the ID of my external hard drive, in this case 0bc2:331a, and then I added it to the following file:
/etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage-quirks.conf
by adding the following line:
options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:331a:u

A reboot later, and the drive is now properly recognized by SMART monitoring tools, and the problem has not yet reoccurred.
The workings of the usb-storage-quirks file are detailed on this site.
